# Having issues with Tailwind and custom fonts

Tags: css, tailwind-css, font-face

My client sent me three fonts, two of which came in the form of a collection of otf files, a "regular," and some variants (i.e., thin, bold, etc.) I'm having trouble with the variants not showing on the page when using Tailwind classes (all the text looks the same).

I'm importing the Regular and Thin in my global.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'EditorsNote';
  src: url('../../public/fonts/editorsNote/EditorsNote-Thin.otf') format('otf');
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'EditorsNote';
  src: url('../../public/fonts/editorsNote/EditorsNote-Regular.otf') format('otf');
  /* font-weight: 400; */
  font-style: normal;
}
```

and this is a snippet from my tailwind.config.ts file:

```
const config: Config = {
 <snip>
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      editorsNote: ['EditorsNote', 'serif'],
      gilroy: ['Gilroy', 'sans-serif'],
    },
    <snip>
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;
```

I have two divs in my component:

```
<div className='text-[100px]  text-black font-editorsNote font-thin '>{title}</div>
<div className='text-[100px]  text-black font-editorsNote '>{title}</div>
```

Despite having font-thin added (verified in Dev Tools, it's there) both text blocks are identical.

I've never done something like this, and I haven't been able to find good consistent documentation. If anybody knows what I'm doing wrong or has a pointer to some reliable docs, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was the format('otf') I changed it to format('opentype'), and it worked. Last time I listen to Google Bard!